# What is the largest and most detailed open dataset for nutrition, maybe with focus on vegan/vegetarianism as of August 2019?

Tags: nutrition

The background is, I am going to write a custom software application for home use, kind of a random picker for good menus for a month.

For that, I am looking for the best dataset you can get for free.

Answer (score 2):

The USDA Food Composition Database is a comprehensive and well-formatted database of nutritional content for various foods. I believe the most recent release was SR28 (Standard Reference 28).

As of 2019, it looks like USDA is setting up a [new website](https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/) for access to this data. You can access data through their API, or you can [download the entire dataset](https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/download-datasets.html) for local processing.

You probably want the `SR Legacy` or `Foundation` data sets. There is no built-in filter for vegetarian or vegan foods so you'll have to filter that yourself, but the vast majority of foundation foods are of plant origin.

*If you do the work of classifying foods as vegetarian/vegan, it might be nice to share your results back out to the community through a site like GitHub. I know there are people who would like to build on that work.*

---

The European Food Safety Authority has a [similar database](https://www.efsa.europa.eu/en/data/food-composition), but I was unable to access it at the time of writing this answer.